# How do I restore data from an offloaded, older version, third party app that I can't re-download? (Iphone 6s, ios 14)

Tags: iphone, itunes, applications, ios-appstore, storage

I use a music player app called Nhaccuatui. I updated it recently, from version 5.x to 6.x. After updating 2 icons appeared on the screen. One works fine and is empty, the other I can't open anymore. I deleted the new version and offloaded the old one. I then tried to reinstall the old one from storage, but it seems that the developer removed that version 5.x from Appstore. The Appstore's "purchased" menu didn't help, there was no popup asking to install the old version. Is there anything I can do to restore the audio files?

Comment: You might want to experiment with the free trial version of [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer) to see if you can find and extract the files. I've been able to recover files through iExplorer that could not have been retrieved by any other method. _Note: very satisfied user of iExplorer - no financial or other ties to Macroplant LLC._

Comment: @IconDaemon I can't find any third party app files, let alone the offloaded ones using iexplorer